# If else Environment variable with PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, environment-variables, config

Can you tell me what is wrong with this config.php file? I think my syntax is wrong somewhere. I want to check the environment variable SERV_ENV to see if the value is local or not and then set the BASE_URL variable based on that.

```
<?php 
   if (getenv('SERV_ENV')='local'); {
        $BASE_URL = "/001_Current_Projects/collegedesis/" 
    else 
        $BASE_URL = "/"
end
}

?>
```

Comment: It looks almost valid on first glance, but it's not really close to real PHP code. Maybe you need to read some more tutorials or books?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic PHP syntax is horribly wrong. Try:

```
<?php
    if( getenv("SERV_ENV") == "local")
        $BASE_URL = "/001_Current_Projects/collegedesis/";
    else
        $BASE_URL = "/";
?>
```

Or, even better:

```
<?php
    $BASE_URL = getenv("SERV_env") == "local" ? "/001_Current_Projects/collegedesis/" : "/";
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if (getenv('SERV_ENV')='local'); {
                      ^
```

You're looking for *comparison* using `==`, not *assignment*, here.

Should I mention the remaining invalid syntax, including missing or misplaced `;` and a weird `end`?

Comment: ok, now I no longer have an error, but my if then statement is still not rendering.. Do you know if I need to restart my computer after creating a new environment variable?

Comment: "Is not rendering"? How do you determine that? And no, no need to restart anything.

Comment: extremely poor choice of words on my part. if statement wasn't returning true. after restart it is, but the base url isn't pointed at the right place now. it's taking the current location of the file and appending what I set the base url I set to the end of it